# How to prevent activity to restart after changing its orientation

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I'm new to android development using KOTLIN, i have activity that contain fragments like the image below (Image 1), the problem is whenever i try to change the orientation from potrait to landscape, the activity return to the previous activity (Like restart it).

I've tried to add `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"` to my `AndroidManifest.xml`, it works perfectly but some says that it's not recommended to use it.

Could you guys tell me or show me example the best practice to solve this problem ?

**IMAGE 1**

[image: Image 1]

**CODE**

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        title = resources.getString(R.string.title_visit)
        loadFragment(VisitFragment())
        navigation_menu.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener)
    }

    private val mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener =
        BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
            when (item.itemId) {
                R.id.menu_visit -> {
                    loadFragment(VisitFragment())
                    title = resources.getString(R.string.title_visit)
                    return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
                }

                R.id.menu_customer -> {
                    loadFragment(CustomerFragment())
                    title = resources.getString(R.string.title_customer)
                    return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
                }

                R.id.menu_new_merchant -> {
                    loadFragment(NewMerchantFragment())
                    title = resources.getString(R.string.title_new_merchant)
                    return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
                }

                R.id.menu_history -> {
                    loadFragment(HistoryFragment())
                    title = resources.getString(R.string.title_history)
                    return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
                }

                R.id.menu_profile -> {
                    loadFragment(ProfileFragment())
                    title = resources.getString(R.string.title_profile)
                    return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
                }
            }
            false
    }

    private fun loadFragment(fragment: Fragment) {
        val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment)
        transaction.addToBackStack(null)
        transaction.commit()
    }
}
```

**VisitFragment.kt**

```
class VisitFragment : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var viewPager: ViewPager
    private lateinit var tabs: TabLayout

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_visit, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        val fragmentAdapter = PagerAdapter(childFragmentManager)
        pager.adapter = fragmentAdapter
        tabs_main.setupWithViewPager(pager)
    }

    fun setNumber() {
        val tabs = tabs_main.getTabAt(0)
        val badge = tabs?.orCreateBadge
        // Customize badge
        badge?.number = 1
    }
}
```

**LatestVisitFragment.kt**

```
class LatestVisitFragment : Fragment() {
    lateinit var latestVisitAdapter: LatestVisitAdapter
    lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    private val testinstance: ArrayList<TestResponseItem> = ArrayList()
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_latest_visit, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        loadDataLatestVisit()
    }

    private fun loadDataLatestVisit(){
        ApiConfig().getService()
            .getUsers()
            .enqueue(object : Callback<List<TestResponseItem>> {
                override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<TestResponseItem>>, t: Throwable) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, t.localizedMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }

                override fun onResponse(
                    call: Call<List<TestResponseItem>>,
                    response: Response<List<TestResponseItem>>
                ) {
                    rv_latest_visit.adapter = LatestVisitAdapter(response.body())
                }

            })
    }
}
```

**LatestVisitAdapter.kt**

```
class LatestVisitAdapter(val data: List<TestResponseItem>?) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<LatestVisitAdapter.MyHolder>() {
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyHolder {
        val v =
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_latest_visit, parent, false)
        return MyHolder(v)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = data?.size ?: 0

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: LatestVisitAdapter.MyHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(data?.get(position))
    }

    class MyHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        fun bind(get: TestResponseItem?) {
            itemView.txt_merchant_name.text = get?.name
            itemView.txt_owner_name.text = get?.email
            val address =
                "${get?.address?.street},${get?.address?.city}, ${get?.address?.suite}, ${get?.address?.zipcode}"
            itemView.txt_address.text = address
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really is not recommended to **prevent activity restart on config changes**.

The recommended ways would either by [saving and restoring UI state](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#saras) or by [using ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel). Either one of them can solve your problem but it's better to use ViewModel approach.

---

### Saving and restoring UI state

#### Saving state

Right before activity start, but right after config changes have been signaled, override `Activity.onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)` if you're saving activity state, or `Fragment.onSaveInstanceState(Bundle) if you're saving fragment state.

```kotlin
override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle?) {
  // Save your data into outState data bundle. And then make sure to
  // call the super method.
  super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
}
```

#### Restoring state

After activity restart due to config changes, restore the previously saved data
and apply it to the UI.

```kotlin
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
  // ... inflate layout, etc...
  if (savedInstanceState != null) {
    // If savedInstanceState is not null, that means this activity is restoring from
    // config changes. All your saved data in onSaveInstanceState() should be accessible
    // from savedInstanceState bundle.
    // ... restore values from savedInstanceState and apply to your views ...
  } else {
    // Initialize vie
  }
}
```

---

### Using ViewModel

This approach is relatively new introduced by Google as part of Android Jetpack library.
Instead of overriding `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle) and checking` savedInstanceState`for null, your data is persisted inside a`ViewModel` and will survive from configuration changes.

#### Basic

Initialize your data inside the `ViewModel` and access them from your activity or fragment.

```kotlin
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {
  var myList: List<User> = emptyList()
  var currentTabIndex: Int = 0

  init {
    // Initialize your data here...
  }
}
```

```kotlin
class MyFragment : Fragment() {
  private val model by viewModels<MyViewModel>()

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    // ... inflate layout, etc...
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(model.currentTabIndex, false)
    // Fetch the values from `ViewModel` and apply to your fragment.
  }
}
```

#### More about `ViewModel`

For better usage of `ViewModel`, it's better to learn from the [official comprehensive guide](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel).